# Taylor Polynomial $\;y = e^{\sin x},\,$ $a = \frac{\pi}{2},\;$ $x = 1.5$

Tags: calculus

$y = e^{\sin x};\;$ $a = \frac{\pi}{2};\;$ $x = 1.5$

So first things get the derivative. I need to calculate the error and the $T_2$

$$f'(x) = \cos x e^{\sin x}$$

$$f''(x) = \cos ^2x e^{\sin x} - \sin x e^{\sin x}$$

So that now gives me

$$f(a) + f'(a)/1 (x-a) + f''(a)/2 (x-a)^2$$

$$e^ {\sin \frac{\pi}{2}} + \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}) e^{\sin {\frac{\pi}{2}}} * (1.5 - \frac{\pi}{2})^2 + \cos ^2 (\frac{\pi}{2}) e^{\sin {\frac{\pi}{2}}} - \sin {\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{\sin {\frac{\pi}{2}}} $$

This turns into $e$ I think.

So for the error

$$|f(x) - T_n (x)| < K \frac{|x - a|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

$$e^{\sin(1.5)} - e <  K \frac{(1.5 - \frac{\pi}{2})^3}{6}$$

That is a mess...where did I go wrong?

Comment: I'm having some issues following your arithmetic, it should be $T_{\frac{\pi}{2},2}(1,5) = e^{1} + \displaystyle\frac{(0)e^{1}}{1,5-\frac{\pi}{2}}+\displaystyle\frac{(0)e^{1}-1e^{1}}{2(1,5-\frac{\pi}{2})^2} = e -\frac{e}{2(1,5-\frac{\pi}{2})^2}$.
It doesn't seem that it turns into $e$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derivatives $f'(x), f''(x)$ are fine. And the following is correct:

$$T_2(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \dfrac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2}\tag{1}$$

Where the problem seems to be is in your evaluation of $(1)$, given $f(a), f'(a), f''(a)$ with $a = \pi/2, x = 1.5$:

> You wrote: $$e^ {\sin \frac{\pi}{2}} + \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}) e^{\sin {\frac{\pi}{2}}} * (1.5 - \frac{\pi}{2})^2 + \cos ^2 (\frac{\pi}{2}) e^{\sin {\frac{\pi}{2}}} - \sin {\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{\sin {\frac{\pi}{2}}} $$

which does not follow from $(1)$.

What you should obtain is:

$$T_2(1.5) = e^{\sin\frac{\pi}{2}} + \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) e^{\sin {\frac{\pi}{2}}}\left(1.5 - \frac{\pi}{2}\right) + \dfrac{\left(\cos ^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) e^{\sin {\frac{\pi}{2}}} - \sin \left({\frac{\pi}{2}}\right) e^{\sin {\frac{\pi}{2}}}\right)\left(1.5 - \frac{\pi}2\right)^2 }{2}$$

$$\begin{align}T_2(1.5) &= e^{1} + {(0)e^{1}}\left (1.5-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+ \dfrac{\left((0)e^{1}-1\cdot e^{‌​1}\right)\left(1.5-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2}{2} \\ \\
& = e -{e}\cdot \dfrac{(1.5-\frac{\pi}{2})^2}{2}\\ \\
& = e\left(1 - \dfrac{\left(1.5 -\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2}{2}\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: nice answer - lots of typing too! :-) +1

Comment: @Amzoti Enjoy the dancing! :-)